# Oracle SQL - How to dynamically replace values of select return?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following view X

```
SELECT 
ssn AS "Return1"
bla AS "Return2"
dla AS "Return3"
FROM v_stored_values
```

When using this view, I want to replace the number value of "svn" with a string value that can be found in the following view Y

```
SELECT 
ssn AS "Return1"
string AS "Return2"
FROM v_ssn
```

So instead of

```
ssn | bla | dla
342   dff   fdd
```

it should be

```
name  | bla | dla
Thomas dff   fdd
```

What would be the best way to combine those two views, who otherwise share no similarities, in a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a join. Assuming that `v_ssn` has columns `ssn` and `name`, that would look like:

```
select s.name return1, v.bla return2, v.dla return3
from v_stored_values v
inner join v_ssn s on s.ssn = v.ssn
```

If there is a possibility that some of `ssn`s from `v_stored_value` are not available in `v_ssn`, you might want to use a `left join` instead, so the records are not eliminated from the resultset.